# Update of 'matplotlib' (1.4.1, following Yosemite update) using 'pip' fails

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, osx-yosemite

Attempting to update `matplotlib` to 1.4.1 (from 1.4.0) [fails with](https://gist.github.com/orome/0963ea06a42cbef25baf)

```
[...]
OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES

                dvipng: yes [version 1.14]

           ghostscript: no

                 latex: yes [version 3.14159265]

               pdftops: no



============================================================================

                        * The following required packages can not be built:

                        * freetype

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Rax/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

and log details

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib
```

Is this something related to my recent update to Yosemite (from Mavericks); or is it related to [recent changes](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) that seem to have been made to `matplotlib`'s `freetype` dependences — or a bit of both? If so, what can I do to address it?

---

UPDATE: Same issue with 1.4.2.

Comment: Why isn't it picking up the wheels? https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=matplotlib&version=1.4.1&:action=display

Comment: Please create an gh issue for this.

Comment: Can you please provide the _full_ output of building.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3694

Comment: @tcaswell: [Full output](https://gist.github.com/orome/0963ea06a42cbef25baf). FWIW, I had `--no-use-wheel`.

Comment: @tcaswell: Fails with [1.4.2. also](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3694#issuecomment-60253308).

Answer (score 0):

I got to install matplotlib on OSX 10.10 reading https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3713.
This is not a solution for pip users; just a way to install matplotlib on my mac waiting for a fix.

I downloaded sources for matplotlib 1.4.2,
changed line 960 in setupext.py as described in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3713/files :

```
'freetype2', 'ft2build.h',
```

becames

```
'freetype2', 'freetype2/ft2build.h'
```

and then compiled and installed with:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```